# Calculate specific matrix in GAMS

Tags: matrix, gams-math

Consider the following data in GAMS:

```
Set i / 0*3 /;

Parameters
    r(i)
    /   2 0.272727
        3 0.8  /
    s(i)
    /   2 0.727273
        3 0.2  /;
```

I want to calculate the following matrix (from this [link](https://www.real-statistics.com/other-mathematical-topics/spline-fitting-interpolation/)):

[image: Text]

So I will end up with the following matrix:

[image: Text]

How to do that in GAMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question the matrix you expect is missing, but I guess, you are looking for something like $-conditions in GAMS and want to do something like this:

Set i / 0*3 /;

```
Parameters
    r(i)
    /   2 0.272727
        3 0.8  /
    s(i)
    /   2 0.727273
        3 0.2  /;
        
Alias (i,j);
Parameter u(i,j);

u(i,j) =   r(i)$(ord(i)=ord(j)+1)
         + 2   $(ord(i)=ord(j)  )
         + s(i)$(ord(i)=ord(j)-1);
```